# CORS request with Ajax/Javascript/Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, xmlhttprequest, cors

I wanna make a CORS get request to, say google (just an example. I'm actually accessing a website that returns json data). Below is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        alert ("success" + data);
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus) {
        alert ("fail" + data);
    }
})
```

With the above code I got this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sdlweb-dev:1234' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

I tried adding code like

```
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With,content-type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        }
```

but still got the same error.

I tried changing dataType from 'json' to 'jsonp'. This way the request is sent, but since the response isn't jsonp, I got another error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Without modifying the server side (I mean the url that I send get request to, because I do not have access to that), can I be able to send CORS request?

Any help is appreciated!!!

Thanks,

Fei

Answer (score 0):

You **must** have access to the server code in order to allow CORS requests.

The headers that you showed should be headers sent back in the response, not in the request.

Comment: Thanks! By server, you mean the server that I'm trying to access, right? (Not my server that I'm hosting my website)

Comment: Also, I'm able to get the response by setting the dataType to "jsonp". But since the returned data type is not "jsonp", is there a way to wrap it somehow and get the content?

Comment: @Feiiiiiiiiiiiii To answer your first comment: yes. To answer your second: no.